# Identify unique/distinct values in a range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I can find frequency of a particular value in a range with countif but i have a different problem. I need to find unique/distinct list from **multiple ranges** and was trying to figure out which worksheet function would be proper in Excel.

For instance I have 8 series of numbers (**multiple ranges**) and need to find unique series in which numbers are not repeated within themselves.

```
1   5   9
1   2   3
4   5   7
2   5   9
2   3   4
6   8   9
1   8   9
3   4   5
```

Expected solution 1 to this problem is

```
1   2   3
4   5   7
6   8   9
```

because `1,2,3` and `4,5,7` and `6,8,9` is not repeated anywhere within themselves in other two series of expected solution 1. I wish to know if this can be achieved using a worksheet formula so that I can get a start or whether I need a vba macro.

`1,2,3` is not repeated anywhere in the next two series of the expected solution 1
`4,5,7` is not repeated in series 1 and series 3 of the expected solution 1
`6,8,9` is not repeated in series 1 and 2 of the expected solution 1

If you see, the below series (Solution 2 3 & 4), they are also unique but these are just two whereas the example expected solution 1 i posted, I got three. Likewise I need to find the maximum

1,5,9 and 2,3,4 (Solution 2)

4,5,7 and 6,8,9 (Solution 3)

2,3,4 and 6,8,9 (Solution 4)

In short, identify maximum numbers of series where numbers within the series are not repeated. In this example, there are maximum 3 such series where numbers are not repeated in the remaining two series (Solution 1).

How can I identify this via formula or macro?

Comment: It is absolutely necessary that you decide **first** if you want to use Google Spreadsheets or Excel. These are totally different programs and therefore totally different answers. Please clarify your tags. • Also I don't see any duplicates in your series the seem all to be unique. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: ok lets go for Excel. I understand 1 is repeated in row 7 but in the end result (solution series) if you see the 3 series, 1,2,3 | 4,5,7 | 6,8,9 not a single number is repeated. I want to identify maximum series where all numbers are unique. I am unable to explain it properly. what I can say is that the numbers should not be repeated in solution series. I am getting downvotes. If I am unable to explain or if you guys think its not a valid question, lets stop here as I do not want more downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the entire question and hope it is more clear. Would expect a worksheet formula so that I can begin from there. A macro would be difficult as I am not that great with programming but I will try though if given a start ! I request all you guys to revoke/undo the downvotes. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This is an insanely complicated question to solve. If this was written in VBA it would be a monster as the potential combinations to check if they contain a solution grows exponentially with the number of rows available to check. Doing this with a worksheet formula would be crazy-town. I don't think you will find a reasonable solution to this.

Comment: Basically it would be "Get values from row 1, iterate the list until you find a second entry that doesn't contain any digits from row 1, now iterate the remainder of the list until you find another record containing no digits from row 1 and the previous row. Now do all that logic again starting with row 2." Not terrible for a small set like this, but a real monster for any reasonably size set.

Comment: I made an attempt at this through VBA. I'm 100% certain that it could be refactored to be a bit more lightweight, but for a small sample it should perform. The resulting dictionary will hold all potential sequences and from there you can pick what you like in subsequent code. Again though, a worksheet formula isn't going to cut it here and a VBA solution will probably lock up if the sample set reaches are very large size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt at what this may look like. I think some downstream code to deal with the dictionary, perhaps finding the dictionary value that has the greatest `len()` would be ideal. This is assuming you have comma delimited values `1,2,3` in column `A` and your sample data is `A1:A8`.

```
Sub FindUniqueSeq()
    Dim rngRow As Range, searchRow As Range
    Dim arrVals As Variant
    Dim arrFound(0 To 9) As String
    Dim seqDict As Dictionary
    Dim lastIndex As Integer


    Set seqDict = New Dictionary

    For Each rngRow In Sheet1.Range("A1:A8")

        arrVals = Split(rngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, ",")
        arrFound(0) = arrVals(0)
        arrFound(1) = arrVals(1)
        arrFound(2) = arrVals(2)

        'iterate through remaining rows
            For Each searchRow In Sheet1.Range("A" & rngRow.Row & ":A8")
                arrVals = Split(searchRow.Cells(1, 1).Value, ",")
                If Not (IsInArray(arrVals(0), arrFound) Or IsInArray(arrVals(1), arrFound) Or IsInArray(arrVals(2), arrFound)) Then
                    'We found some unique values
                    'figure out where to stick these
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arrFound)
                        If arrFound(i) = "" Then
                            lastIndex = i
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                    'Insert
                    arrFound(0 + lastIndex) = arrVals(0)
                    arrFound(1 + lastIndex) = arrVals(1)
                    arrFound(2 + lastIndex) = arrVals(2)
                End If
            Next

        'add sequence to dictionary and redim array
        seqDict.Add Join(arrFound, ","), "Row" & rngRow.Row
        Debug.Print Join(arrFound, ",") 'print out so we can see what's happening
        Erase arrFound

    Next

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Again though, this is going to be a bear as your data grows.

Comment: Hey... thanx. This works for me. My actual data set is not that huge. I can go upto a maximum grid of 5x25 (5 cols and 25 rows). Will make changes to the code that suits my needs and will reply to this comment if I get stuck somewhere. thank you very much for your assistance. really appreciate a lot !

Comment: I am trying to understand the whole code. Can you please tell me the logic behind the line `Dim arrFound(0 To 9) As String` ? Is it because the maximum digit/number is 9 or is it because I have 8 rows or is there something else? I just want to check that if my grid is 5x25 and maximum number/digit is 35, what should I have it there?

Comment: That is declaring the variable `arrFound` as an array (because of the parentheses) . It should be `(0 to 8)` to hold 9 values (in indexes 0,1,2,3... 8) but I messed that up. So you would want `Dim arrFound(0 to 4) As String`. The string just says what type of values the array will hold. You could use `int` but you might have to monkey with the function. The function is also not super necessary as one could do something like `Instr(arrVals(0), Join(arrFound, ","))` as the test too since it's unlikely that substrings will be an issue here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean to say it should have been (0 to 2) for the example shown and (0 to 4) for my 5x25 grid ??. I am ok with the string and int is not required if I have to play with the function as I am not a pro in programming. I really did not understand why you said the function is not necessary.

Comment: The `arrFound` array will hold all of the potential unique combinations. We knew that there could only be 9 unique combinations as there are only 9 digits (1-9). So the array should have, in the example script, be declared as (0 to 8) as that would create an array with 9 spaces/indexes (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8). I guess that (0 to 4) wouldn't make sense for you in your 5x25 grid. I'm not sure what the right answer would be though since I don't know how many unique values you anticipate. If it's a variable number you could declare it to be very large (0 to 500) or use `redim preserve` to resize.

Answer (score 1):

Well OK Ive been puzzling for a while as to how you might do this just with formulas. Just to show that it is feasible for the sort of scale that OP is talking about, here is a possible method:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$C$8,0,MOD(COLUMN()+2,3)+1),MATCH(0,MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(FIND($A1:INDEX(1:1,INT((COLUMN()-1)/3)*3),$A$1:$A$8&"|"&$B$1:$B$8&"|"&$C$1:$C$8))),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A1:INDEX(1:1,INT((COLUMN()-1)/3)*3)))),0)),"")
```

The idea is that you check all the rows for the three numbers in the current row and pull out the first row that contains no matches. Then you pull the formula across and check the six numbers that you now have, and so on. Eventually the formula errors out.

[image]

The formula has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thats great! Thanks for your time and effort. I am going to try this for larger sets of numbers. Thank you so much